# bash - in vim - instead of / it gives <F2> on numeric keyboard

Tags: bash, shell, vim, sh

I am using vim for writing script and when I press `/` it gives me `<F2>` and others are also "messed up"... Dunno what i did, or why is that, by is it possible to make it function normally??? Don't ask me why. It's school project. Thanks guys.

Comment: Check your `.vimrc` to see if someone remapped the `/` key.

Comment: In addition to @chepner's comment, in a vim session, enter `:map`. Also `:iabbr`

Comment: You write 'on numeric keyboard' in the title. Does it mean the `/` key on the other part of the keyboard works fine ?

Comment: Looks like `/` will get you `<Esc>OQ` in application mode (when the NumLock light is off). This is going to vary a bit depending on your OS, your terminal, your windowing system, and any custom config. There's probably no works-anywhere solution, but toggling NumLock on/off might make it work in most cases. Beyond that, try `:map <C-v>/`. Press Ctrl+v; don't type that literally. That will tell Vim to escape the next character sequence, and should show you exactly what pressing `/` is generating. You can then map that to anything you want.